# How to get content of JTable if cell contains checkbox

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, checkbox, jtable

I have created a JTable in Netbeans of which the first column consists of checkboxes.

These checkboxes were made by adding

```
JCheckBox checkBox = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
```

and

```
jTable1.getColumn("ColumnName").setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(checkBox));
```

under 
**customize code** when right-clicking the JTable. And in the **Table Contents** I specified the datatype to ***Boolean*** (I basically followed along the instructions on this website since I had never worked with JTables before: http://forums.netbeans.org/topic9007.html)

My question now: how do I get the actual checkbox in row=1 & coloumn=1, for example? 
These attempts aren't working:

```
JCheckBox j = (JCheckBox) jTable1.getComponent(1);

JCheckBox j = (JCheckBox) jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1);
```

I get the error message *"java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.swing.JCheckBox"*.

For what I'm trying to do, I need to get back the object/component of type "checkbox" and NOT just find out if it is selected or not. Is that possible to do? I'm not super advanced in programming, so that's why I'm having trouble.

Comment: Maybe it is easier/better to just get the Boolean value of a cell if that is much easier than what I first tried to do. Any tips on how that works? All my attempts (like: Boolean r1c1 = (Boolean)jTable1.getValueAt(1, 1)) haven't worked.

Comment: since I had never worked with JTables before == Oracle tutorial - How to use tables show correct way, don't put JComponents to the JTable/TaleModel, there is stored only value for the view

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: old answer below, was reminded that going through the `TableModel` to get the `boolean` value directly is a safer bet than messing about with `JTable` UI :)

Don't try to cast anything to `JCheckBox`, instead iterate through the `Model` to get to the values you want.

---

The `Component` list includes everything defined within the `Object`, so you might not always get the specific element you want.

I recommend looping through the `Components` and using `instanceof` to check if it matches `JCheckBox`.

```
for(Component c : jTable1.getComponents[]) {
    if(c instanceof javax.swing.JCheckBox) {
        // do the stuff
    } else {
        // don't do the stuff
    }
}
```

Or even iterate through the `Components` in the first column, might make things easier.

Comment: not there (XxxTableModel) must be stored Boolean value not JCheckBox, then JTable shows JCheckBox in view correctly